# Accessing child page directly without parent props

Tags: reactjs

Apologies if this has been asked before but couldn't find a satisfactory answer anywhere else.

I have two components - `Parent` and `Child`, and two routes.

```
// App.js
<Route path="/parent" component={Parent} />
<Route path="/child/:name" component={Child} />
```

```
// Parent.js
// accessible at /parent

const Parent = () => {
  const history = useHistory()

  const children = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Bob', age: 10, school: 'ABC' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Kate', age: 10, school: 'XYZ' },
  ];

  return (
    <>
    <button
      onClick={history.push({
        to: `/child/${children[0]['name']}`,
        state: children[0],
      })}
    >
      Child 1
    </button>
    <button
    onClick={history.push({
      to: `/child/${children[1]['name']}`,
      state: children[1],
    })}
  >
    Child 2
  </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
// Child.js
// accessible at /child/:name

const Child = ({ name, age, school }) => {
  return (
   <p>{name}</p>
   <p>{age}</p>
   <p>{school}</p>
  )
}
```

Now if I go to `Parent`, select a child, I will see the `Child` component with all the data. However, if I bypass the parent page completely and go directly to `/child/Bob` url on browser, the props are `undefined` and I won't see any data on the child page.

What is the general solution to this problem? I can think of checking for props on `Child` and if non-existent, redirect to `Parent` using `history.push()`. This is to prevent users from accessing `Child` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [useParams()](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) in that case

check if `childName` is undefined then,

```
const {name} =  useParams();
```

`name` will then have your Url Param

**UPDATE**

Eventually what the ideal routing would work is, you always render the Parent component and then have routes inside your parent Component. For eg Master route match /child export component Parent, then inside parent, have a route Child/:name, export Child

Master
Route

```
<Route path={`${match.url}child`} component={Parent} />
```

Inside Parent, pass as many props you want

```
<Route exact path="/child/:name" component={Child} childName={yourVar} />
```

Comment: This solution would work in this simple example but what if I am passing more props.

Comment: yeah, eventually what the ideal routing would work is, you always render the Parent component and then have routes inside your parent Component. For eg Master route match /child export component Parent, then inside parent, have a route Child/:name, export Child

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render different name within you `h1` in your child component then you have an awesome solution given by @Tushar. If you want to render a default value when the props are not passed to the child either via route or parents then you can have a defaultProps within your component. For eg.

```
const Child = ({ childName }) => {
  return <h1>{childName}</h1>
}

Child.defaultProps = { childName: 'Whatever value you want to render' };
```